# Div filled with white transparent background which goes to complete transparent at the edge

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that I want to replace by CSS3, because it is easier to swap colours, etc. But I am struggling a bit with the CSS, playing with

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

But I can't seem to get the effect that I need which is

[image]

on the page I have a div... so code is quite simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
    <div class="whitebackground">
        Content in black here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion to get the same effect working in CSS3?

Thanks

Comment: linear-gradient with transparent colors (using rgba values) on top of the image?

Comment: but gradient is on the top, left and bottom... not at the right... not sure how I would do it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely what you are trying to achieve. You have an image or drawing for a better visualization?

Comment: Updated the screenshot, let me know if it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would achieve this using a box shadow that matches the opacity of the white background div.

On the white background div something like:

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 25px rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/500');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 80px;
}

.whitebackground {
  padding: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 25px rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="whitebackground">
    <h1> Content in here </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That gives me something to work with! Awesome, thanks a lot!